# jQuery - trouble with not() selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Within 'div.row:visible' I want to fadeOut all children() which don't have the class span.sandwich:visible, although I'm having trouble figuring it out.

here's what I have so far

```
$('div.row:visible').children('span.sandwich:visible').not('.sandwich:visible').fadeOut('200');
```

which doesn't seem to work, could anyone help me out here

html

```
<div class='row'>
    <span class='sandwich'>sandwich</span>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <span class='not-sandwich'>not sandwich</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `doesn't seem to work`. **What** does "not" seem to work? What are your expectations, what actually happens? Where's the HTML code?

Comment: 'Within 'div.row:visible' I want to fadeOut all children() which don't have the class span.sandwich:visible'

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly getting confused with the selector within children, have you tried something like the following, which should select all of the children and then narrow that selection:

```
$('div.row:visible').children().not('.sandwich:visible').fadeOut('200');
```

Comment: Thank you that's perfect.

Although, I actually want to fade the parent() rather than the children.

I was thinking $('div.row:visible').children().not('.sandwich:visible').parent().fadeOut('200'); although seems to fade all elements instead of just the ones without the .sandwich:visible selector

Comment: I'm pretty sure CSS Limits prevent you from fading only the parent.  When the parent fades, so does every child.

Comment: Yeah, I don't mind fading the children, I just want to fade the parent() which don't contain the '.sandwich:visible' selector

Comment: You could also do the same by moving the selector from `not()` to `children()`.  That might give you very marginally better perf too (not sure how jQuery works internally, but I imagine fewer children would mean fewer iterations), and should be logically the same.

Comment: good idea.

I tried that although, 

$('div.row:visible').children(':not(.sandwich:visible)').parent().fadeOut('200');

It still fades all rows and doesn't keep the '.sandwich:visible' visible

Comment: @user863739: I meant move the selector (the string inside those method calls is called a selector) `$('...').children('span.sandwich:visible').not().etc`.  If you edit the question to provide some stripped down HTML that shows the problem you're having it will be easier for us to debug your newer problem w/ parents.

Comment: Edited. Your code seems to fade the sandwiches instead of the others.

Comment: That code wasn't for the parents problem, just to recommend where to put the sandwich selector.  Try this instead: `$('div.row:visible').children('span.sandwich:visible').not().parent().fadeOut(200);`

Answer (score 0):

I've run into trouble before daisy-chaining jQuery selection methods, and I was able to get around these issues by nesting selectors, as below:

`$($($('div.row:visible').children('span.sandwich:visible')).not('.sandwich:visible')).fadeOut('200');`

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification:

> which don't have the class `span.sandwich:visible`

`span.sandwich:visible` is not a class.

`sandwich` is a class.

`span.sandwich` is any `span` element with a `sandwich` class.

`span.sandwich:visible` is any `span` element with a `sandwich` class that is `visible`.

So trying to interpret your question, I get:

> Within 'div.row:visible' ...

Within visible `div` elements with the class `row`...

> I want to fadeOut all children() which don't have the class span.sandwich:visible

You want to `fadeOut()` all **not**`visible` `span` elements with the class `sandwich`, which are children of the `div.row`.

To me, that translates to

`$('div.row:visible').children('span.sandwich:not(:visible)').fadeOut('200');`

**Given your HTML you just added:**

`$('span').not('.sandwich').fadeOut(200);`

*Will fade out entire span:*

`<span class='not-sandwich'>not sandwich</span>`

`$('span').not('.sandwich').parent().fadeOut(200);`

*Will fade out entire div:*

```
<div class='row'>
    <span class='not-sandwich'>not sandwich</span>
</div>
```

***FINAL EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS***

http://jsfiddle.net/DDmsh/4/

and if you want to specify only `div.row` parents:  http://jsfiddle.net/DDmsh/5/

Comment: I want to fade the parent not the child

Comment: What exactly in English are you trying to do?  Fade out rows that aren't sandwiches?  Your HTML you added to the question has almost no relation to the JS code you posted.

Comment: I want to fade out the 'div.row' which doesn't have the children 'span.sandwich'